# Batch Capture incoming Netstat IPs as variable

Tags: batch, ip, netstat, capture, icmp

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can capture (and if possible, log) the ip addresses displayed from 'netstat' command. I'm trying to make a script that waits for a ping from a specific host. Is there any way of capturing this information into workable variable than I can then use in a script?  I have piped the output to a text file, but I still don't understand any way to go about capturing the IP's from the text file into variables

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried redirecting netstat's output to a text file, as such: `netstat > log.txt`?

Comment: Is this [PowerShell script](http://www.kennethghartman.com/log-connections-powershell-script/) from Shay Levi something for you?

Comment: I am currently piping results to .txt file, and I will take a look into the powershell script. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have a text file with IPs, and you just want the IPs, then netstat becomes irrelevant.

get grep from gnuwin32 and the right regex. This will do it

```
C:\blah>grep -oP (\d{1,3}\.){1,3}\d{1,3} filewithips
```

try `arp -a>myfile` or netstat -aon>a   then you have a file of IPs among other info and you just want the IPs now run that grep command I gave you on it and you get just the IPs

or this

```
C:\>netstat -aon | grep -oP (\d{1,3}\.){1,3}\d{1,3}
```

will output a list of IPs

You could run a for loop on that just reading each line into a variable

then it's not a question of reading IPs just reading lines of a file.

Answer (score 0):

This script demonstrates how to save `netstat`'s output IPs into variables within PowerShell

Just run the script in PowerShell ISE, open a new browser,  go to www.google.com and see whats happening.

```
$allIPs = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("www.google.com")
$myIP = $allIPs[0].IPAddressToString

while ($true) {
  cls
  netstat -n | select-string "$myIP.*ESTABLISHED" | foreach {
    $part = $_.line.split(' ',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
    $localIP  = $part[1] -replace ":.*", "" 
    $remoteIP = $part[2] -replace ":.*", "" 
    write-host $localIP  $remoteIP
  }
  sleep 2
}
```

Once started, it queries all connections with `netstat -n` every 2 seconds (`while ($true)` together with `sleep 2`).

To speed up netstat, `-n` (numeric) is the most important parameter since no DNS lookups are made. You can read more about other parameters like `-a` and `-o` at [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490947.aspx)

Next, PowerShell filters on only established connections (`select-string "$myIP.*ESTABLISHED"`) to e.g. www.google.com. This is just an example to show how it works. Change

```
$myIP = $allIPs[0].IPAddressToString
```

to the IP which you are waiting for a ping

```
$myIP = '192.168.1.1'
```

The last part is to split up the lines by spaces (`$_.line.split(' '`), remove those spaces afterwards (`[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries`), remove the port (`-replace ":.*", ""`) and save the results to their according variables.

You can do what ever you want with them. I just echoed them with `write-host $localIP  $remoteIP`

Comment: that looks very cool, though powershell is not batch.. also, regarding netstat -n every two seconds... I would note that there is a program  MS 'port reporter' that is like a continuous logged netstat though ms port reporter seens to only do tcp