# Grep a destination IP in Netstat results in realtime - windows 7

Tags: networking

Does anyone know how to get grep working so you can tail netstat results in windows 7 CMD?

Comment: @D.W. can you quote from the FAQ? Your link goes to a 'tour' and the word "information security" leads to http://security.stackexchange.com/  So it's not clear whether you mean it's not suitable on SU or it's not suitable on security.stackexchange

Comment: this link may help http://superuser.com/questions/764746/batch-capture-incoming-netstat-ips-as-variable  it might do it in powershell with netstat though I haven't tested it.  for linux apparently there's netstat -c and the watch command, and perhaps there's a windows equivalnet of watch. Technically tcpdump can do it but you'd have to filter and interpret it.

Comment: @barlop, sorry about that.  The question was originally on security.stackexchange, and I closed-voted it there as off-topic (meaning it is not suitable on security.stackexchange).  It's since been migrated over to SU, triggering your confusion.